# Having more than one site in IIS7

Tags: iis-7

suppose I have two domains

- www.site1.com
- www.site2.com

To publish them on the same IIS server I have created 2 virtual directories `/site1` and `/site2`.

How can I associate every name with its own virtual directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than set them up as virtual directories, set each site up as their own Web Site. Then edit the bindings of each Web Site, and specify the appropriate domain name for each site

[image: IIS Site Bindings]

Comment: But if I create two sites they both shares the same port and so only one can be started at a time

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesnt seem to make sense,

'How can I associate every name with its own virtual directory?' - what does this mean what do you mean by name?

Also you dont have to make 2 VD's for 2 websites. Just make 2 websites...and use one dns for each one.